# Partial string extraction with stringr - getting NA

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm trying to extract part of a string using stringr.

I'm aiming for the output to be E5_1_C33 and E5_1_C23, but instead I'm getting NA.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
library(stringr)
mystring <- c("can_ComplianceWHOInfrastructurePol_E5_1_C33","can_ComplianceWHOInfrastructurePol_E5_1_C23")
str_extract(mystring, "A\\d_\\d_B\\d\\d$")
```

Comment: Uhm, your input (and expected output) contains `E…C…` but your regular expression pattern contains `A…B…`. See the problem?

Comment: Oh goody,clear evidence I'm useless after 9 pm. Thanks @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 0):

slightly modified your line , as as need any letter not only A and B:

```
str_extract(mystring, "[A-z]\\d_\\d_[A-z]\\d\\d$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an R base approach using `gsub`

```
> gsub(".*(\\w{2}_\\w{1}_\\w{3})$", "\\1", mystring)
[1] "E5_1_C33" "E5_1_C23"
```